# Unable to save component when using this string: "() {}"

Tags: cme, 2011-sp1, component

I'm using 2011 SP1 HR2 and just ran across this most strange error. When I have the following string in any simple text component field `() {}` - an open/close parenthesis followed by a space character followed by open/close curly brackets, I'm then unable to save the component and I get the following error:

**WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/General.svc/SaveItem failed to execute. STATUS (0).**

If you remove this string, you can save the component normally. I'm currently using this string in some .NET code (creating a VB.NET array). There's definitely a workaround and other methods of creating arrays that don't involve using this string, but I am curious as to why it's failing now. I've had this code in a Tridion component since 5.3 through 2011 SP1 HR1. I recently upgraded to SP1 HR2 and so I'm wondering if something changed in this hotfix rollup.

Has anyone come across this before? I've also opened a ticket with customer support and I'll update this question once I get a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested with 2011sp1hr1, hr2, firefox latest version, latest chrome version, no issue there.

Actually, it was suspected the cause is due to the McAfee Advisor.  The new definition of this software somehow interferes with Tridion operation. (per Haniel)

Answer (score 8):

Those characters are also used for the "[Shellshock bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug))" (a Bash vulnerability discovered recently) that is currently all the rage.

It's possible that a security update outside of Tridion (firewall, Windows Update, anti-virus, etc.) is preventing the request from going through. Check all your logs!

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. The Tridion logs themselves don't show further errors, but I'll check all the other Windows and anti-virus logs.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this in Tridion 2013 SP1 and cannot replicate the issue.  So it sounds like a defect that has been addressed since your version.

Does the CM's event viewer log give you more details about this save error, e.g. stacktrace?  If you share it, we may be able to help further.  Otherwise, feel comforted that the issue is addressed in the next Tridion version already.